# Constraint violation spring JPA only on some records

Tags: java, database, spring, jpa, constraints

I get a violated constraints exception for the Dependency entity, but it is only happening on old records. My last change was adding a `mappedBy=kpi`-Attribute to the parent entity named KPIBusiness.

I can delete newly created parent entities having dependencies but not the old ones.

KPIBusiness.java:

```
@Entity
public class KPIBusiness extends KPI {

    private Long businessProcessId;
    private String businessProcess;

    private Long eventId;
    private String event;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="kpi", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)   
    private Set<Dependency> dependencies;
}
```

Dependency.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="dependencies")
public class Dependency {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long did;

    public Long getDid() {
        return did;
    }

    public void setDid(Long did) {
        this.did = did;
    }   
    private AlertConstants.TRIGGER kpiType;

    private Long kpiId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id", nullable=false)  
    private KPIBusiness kpi;
}
```

Exception:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referentielle Integrität
>   verletzt: "FKSKW30595DULXL90POB2K9KT3I:
>   PUBLIC.KPIBUSINESS_DEPENDENCIES FOREIGN KEY(DEPENDENCIES_DID)
>   REFERENCES PUBLIC.DEPENDENCIES(DID) (33)"
>       Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKSKW30595DULXL90POB2K9KT3I: PUBLIC.KPIBUSINESS_DEPENDENCIES FOREIGN
>   KEY(DEPENDENCIES_DID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.DEPENDENCIES(DID) (33)"; SQL
>   statement:
>       delete from dependencies where did=? [23503-196]

I was using this code:

```
repository.delete(currentKPI);
repository.flush();
```

And am now considering using this code:

```
currentKPI.setDependencies(new HashSet<Dependency>());
currentKPI = repository.save(currentKPI);
repository.flush();//HACK delete at first try
repository.delete(currentKPI);
repository.flush();
```

However it appears that `currentKPI.setDependencies(dependencies);` does not update the dependencies at all. I use this code to try and change the dependencies:

```
Set<Dependency> dependencies = new HashSet<Dependency>();
for(RemoteKPINames kpi : tcsDependencies.getValue()) {
    Dependency dependency = new Dependency();
    dependency.setKpiId(kpi.getId());
    dependency.setKpiType(kpi.getType());
    dependency.setKpi(data);
    dependencies.add(dependency);
}

log.info("Setting dependencies in data object #={}", dependencies.size());
data.setDependencies(dependencies);
```

Comment: You can't delete without setting a cascade (perhaps to All?) since you have foreign keys referencing the row that you want to delete

Comment: There is a `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` at the parents OneToMany statement.

Comment: @OneToMany(mappedBy="kpi", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)

Answer (score 1):

**EmployeeEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class EmployeeEntity implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1798070786993154676L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer           employeeId;
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String            firstName;
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String            lastName;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private Set<AccountEntity> accounts;

    //Getters and Setters Ommited
}
```

**AccountEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Account")
public class AccountEntity implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer           accountId;
    @Column(name = "ACC_NO", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String            accountNumber;

    @OneToOne (mappedBy="accounts",  fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private EmployeeEntity employee;

}
```

Look at the bold line in above source code for EmployeeEntity.java. It defines “cascade=CascadeType.ALL” and it essentially means that any change happened on EmployeeEntity must cascade to AccountEntity as well. If you save an employee, then all associated accounts will also be saved into database. If you delete an Employee then all accounts associated with that Employee also be deleted. Simple enough.

But what if we only want to cascade only save operations but not delete operation. Then we need to clearly specify it using below code.

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
private Set<AccountEntity> accounts;
```

Now only when save() or persist() methods are called using employee instance then only accounts will be persisted. If any other method is called on session, it’s effect will not affect/cascade to accounts.

**JPA Cascade Types**

The cascade types supported by the Java Persistence Architecture are as below:

1. CascadeType.PERSIST : means that save() or persist() operations
   cascade to related entities.
2. CascadeType.MERGE : means that related entities are merged when the
   owning entity is merged.
3. CascadeType.REFRESH : does the same thing for the refresh()
   operation.
4. CascadeType.REMOVE : removes all related entities association with
   this setting when the owning entity is deleted.
5. CascadeType.DETACH : detaches all related entities if a “manual
   detach” occurs.
6. CascadeType.ALL : is shorthand for all of the above cascade
   operations.

Answer (score 1):

Your cascade is meant to be used from the parent (`KPIBusiness`) to the child (`Dependency`). It won't work the other way. Your `Dependency` won't be (magically) removed from any collections that contain it.

Option 1:

Remove the `Dependency` from `KPIBusiness` *and* delete it. Find a sample code below:

```
// start a transaction
Dependency dependencyToBeDeleted;
KPIBusiness kpiBusiness;
...
kpiBusiness.getDependencies().remove(dependencyToBeDeleted);
dependencyRepository.remove(dependencyToBeDeleted);
// commit the transaction
```

Option 2:

Extend the `@OneToMany` annotation for the `Set<Dependencies>` with `orphanRemoval=true` ([Example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Orphan_Removal_(JPA_2.0))). Then, it's sufficient to remove the `Dependency` from the Collection in `KPIBusiness` and JPA will automatically delete it from the database when it's not being referenced anymore.

Make sure you fully understand the usage of *DELETE cascades* and *orphanRemoval*. It's always better to get an error instead of JPA silently deleting stuff that you never meant to be deleted.

Comment: I don't have a dependencyRepository yet and so would go for Option 2

Comment: That was just a sample. It works just as well with the ``entityManager``. The DependencyRepository would use the entityManager eventually, anyway.

Comment: I looked at the database now with the H2 console. I seem to have both a Join Column named ID in Dependencies and also have a Table named `KPIBUSINESS_DEPENDENCIES`. The latter table seems to hold the dependencies that are fetched, while the id column holds a lot of junk undeleted rows. What should I change so I only have a single way the database represents the relationship? Should I remove the JoinColumn?

Comment: I deleted the database so that it gets recreated without the `KPIBUSINESS_DEPENDENCIES` table